# Is there some other way to describe a formal language other than grammars?

Tags: grammar, formal-languages

I'm looking for the mathematical theory which deals with describing formal languages (set of strings) in general and not just grammar hierarchies.

Comment: I suggest you ask your question in http://cstheory.stackexchange.com instead

Comment: That would be a good idea but then why are there relevant tags for this subject on stackoverflow?

Comment: Because not every question that involves these concepts is off-topic here and is a better fit for another site.

Answer (score 0):

Grammars give you the algorithm that lists all possible strings in the language.  You could specify the algorithm any other way, but grammars are a concise and well-accepted format to do so.

Another way is to list every string that belongs to the language -- this will only work if the set of strings in the language is small (and definitely not when the set is infinite).

Comment: I know but what other "concise and well-accepted" formats are there to describe languages?

Comment: Write a computer program, for example.  You do not need to run the program -- the code itself is an encoding of the language (the set of strings belonging to the language).  If you run the program , you are actually generating the strings in the language, just like when "running" the grammar (applying the rules).

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are a formalism for describing a set of languages, for instance. Although there are algorithms for transforming regular grammars and expressions in both ways, they are still two different theories. Also, automata (as a plural of automaton) can help you describe languages, not just DFA and NFA which describe the same set as regular languages, but 2DFA, stack automata. For example, a two-stacks automata is as powerful as a Turing machine. Finally, Turing machines itself are a formalism for languages. For any Turing machine, the set of all string on which the given Turing machine stops on a finite number of steps is a formally defined language.

Comment: Do you know if there are any algorithms which induce automata from string examples?

Comment: You know, I've have been thinking about it for some time. We have experimented here in my faculty with adjusting regular expressions to samples, just like adjusting any function to some data. We have an idea somewhat like using some metaheuristic for finding the minimun error between a regular expression and a set of samples. But I don't know what's out there.

Comment: Actually, there is a whole branch called "grammatical inference" which deals with exactly that problem. You can probably start around there. Check wikipedia.